# Clicking on a desktop shortcut should open Outlook message in Encrypted mode

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, outlook

I have a shortcut on Windows desktop with mailto: in it that when clicked opens Outlook message for the user to enter their question. The email message needs to convey PHI and currently this is not possible since the shortcut opens the email in Outlook without encryption. I want the encryption to be automatically enabled every time the shortcut is clicked and Outlook message is opened without the intervention of the user and without them having to click on the Encrypt button in Outlook, I wonder if this doable? Is there a command line switch for Outlook that will launch a message in Encrypted mode? should this be implemented by a batch or PowerShell rather that just a shortcut with mailto: in it?

Comment: Please explain what PHI means.

Comment: Private health information

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with a mail link. You have to create an Outlook mail template `.oft` with the encryption setting enabled. Setting this up is outside of the scope of StackOverflow (try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for how to create an Outlook template), but once you have said template you can `Invoke-Item $pathToTemplate` to automatically create a new email from the template.

That said this isn't going to be ideal if end users are outside of your organization. You also can't guarantee they will be emailing you using Outlook as their email client either, if you are talking about patients using a portal or something. If you are trying to solve this for patients or other external providers, I would query [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or another community to find out how other health providers are solving the email end-to-end encryption solution when patient communication is involved.

In fact... I'd recommend not using PowerShell at all for this, despite that you can launch the template from PowerShell. Just use an email template if this is for internal use, ask SuperUser or similar community for advice if this is for external use.